# SHA1 digest from two PDFs is different but when converted to PDF/A is equal

Tags: java, hash, pdfa

I generate two PDFs from a jasper passing the same parameters to both of them, when I hash these two PDFs their hash is different which I think is the correct result, because eventough they have the same content they were created at different times. 
But when I convert these two PDFs to PDF/A their sha1 hash is equal.

Can someone help me with this issue? How is this possible?

EDIT:

```
  private static final String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "fi_pdfa";

  public void convert(String exeFullPath, String inputFile,
                    String outputFile, String fontDirectory) {
    String[] execParams = new String[4];

    execParams[0] = exeFullPath;

    execParams[1] = "\"inputpath_u=" + base64Encode(inputFile) + "\"";
    execParams[2] = "\"outputpath_u=" + base64Encode(outputFile) + "\"";
    execParams[3] = "\"outputid=" + OUTPUT_FORMAT + "\"";

  //  execParams[1] = "inputpath_u=\"" + base64Encode(inputFile) + "\"";
  //  execParams[2] = "outputpath_u=\"" + base64Encode(outputFile) + "\"";
  //  execParams[3] = "outputid=" + OUTPUT_FORMAT;
  //  execParams[4] = "fontdirectory=\"" + fontDirectory + "\"";

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = null;
    ExportStatusCode statusCode = null;
    ExportShutdownHook shutdownHook = null;
    try {
        process = runtime.exec(execParams);


        // Install a shutdown hook to perform cleanup if we're interrupted.
        shutdownHook = new ExportShutdownHook(process);
        runtime.addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);

        process.waitFor();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
           System.out.println(line);
        reader.close(); 
        runtime.removeShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
        shutdownHook.finished();

        statusCode = new ExportStatusCode(process.exitValue());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
        if (shutdownHook != null) {
            runtime.removeShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
            shutdownHook.finished();
        }
        statusCode = ExportStatusCode.SCCERR_JAVA_IO_ERROR;
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
        runtime.removeShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
        shutdownHook.finished();
        process.destroy();
        statusCode = ExportStatusCode.SCCERR_JAVA_INTERRUPTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see how you are converting them, please.

Comment: I'm using Oracle OutsideIn...

Comment: Without looking at your actual code, I am gonna have to start guessing at what you did. Did you declare a main method?

Comment: Added the code on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I don't believe it is an issue with your code so much as with the PDF/A converter being used.

There are some PDF features that require or suggest a timestamp be used (e.g. digital signatures, annotations, PieceInfo dictionaries), and there are some features that require or suggest a unique identifier be used.

The PDF Reference strongly recommends that PDF Producers generate File Identifiers (stored in an array in the trailer dictionary), so even if the rest of the files were created identically, the ID entries in the trailer dictionary should be unique and cause the hash value for the files to be different...which strongly indicates that the ID array is either not being populated by the PDF Converter or that the generation of the identifiers is flawed;  This can be verified by opening the two PDFs in a Hex Viewer and scrolling to the bottom of the files.

Disclaimer: Once upon a time, I provided technical support for the OutsideIn products.